# Django filtering: model instance vs model pk

Tags: python, django

I stumbled upon (for me, at least) some rather odd behaviour in Django. I'm not sure if this is supported/allowed behaviour.

Suppose I have the following model:

```py
class Club
    name = CharField(....)
    memberships = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through=ClubMembership, related_name='clubs')

    def getMembership(self, personID):
        return ClubMembership.objects.get(club_id=self.id, person_id=personID)
```

Obviously, `getMembership` returns the associated `ClubMembership` instance (For now, let's assume we only call this method for persons that are in fact in the club).

Now, when calling this method, I found that:

```py
club = Club.objects.get(...)
person = Person.objects.get(...)

membership = club.getMembership(person)
```

and

```py
club = Club.objects.get(...)
person = Person.objects.get(...)

membership = club.getMembership(person.id)
```

are both yielding the correct membership. Is there some *magic* happening inside the `filter`/`get` methods that check if the passend keyword (for `person_id`) is in fact an integer (pk) or a model instance?

If both is valid and allowed, what are the implications? Any differences performance wise? Which would be the preferred method?

Ofc I could filter against the entire person model and not just the id, like so:

```py
def getMembership(self, person):
        return ClubMembership.objects.get(club_id=self.id, person=person)
```

But afaik, this would be a lot slower, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in [Queries over related objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#queries-over-related-objects) section of documentation there's no difference between an integer (pk) or a model instance.

In their example, if you have a Blog object b with id=5, the following three queries would be identical:

```
Entry.objects.filter(blog=b) # Query using object instance
Entry.objects.filter(blog=b.id) # Query using id from instance
Entry.objects.filter(blog=5) # Query using id directly
```

Comment: And this also holds true for the "reverse" way? .filter(obj=inst), .filter(obj_id=inst)?

Comment: Yes, Django boils it all down to SQL queries (they affect speed the most) which end up being the same.

Comment: ... and `Entry.objects.filter(blog_id=b)`, etc.